# How to bind firebase database user and user data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I don't really know what to search regarding this specific question but recently I just did
a login/sign up feature on my app with firebase and it works great.

Context of what I wanna do:

This app already has a working assessment feature that will give a score to the user and will store the score in their profile.

The problem is how do I make sure that the score (and other user info) will be bound to a  specific user that is currently logged in?

How do I make it so that when a specific user does an assessment their score will fall into their own node?

example of what I want to accomplish:

```
>USER1 signs up.  
  
 >USER1 will take the assessment. 
     
   >After USER1 takes an assessment 
      he will go to the profile to see his results 
      as well as his basic info like fullname,username and age.
```

This is the sample of my firebase database.

[image]

Thank you! I will keep searching I just need a little bit of help cause I don't really know what to search about this specific thing.

Comment: check this https://github.com/sunil-singh-chaudhary/FirebaseDemo/tree/master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user is logged in, then you can simply do:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userId = user.getUid();
```

Now you have access to the `userId`. Then if you want to add a new score to the database, you can do:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Score");
ref.child(userId).child("result").setValue(1);
```

This will give you the following database:

```
Score
   userId
     result : 1
```